# Python TKINTER label not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code that I wrote for a calculator for my college coding class. For some reason, the label I added does not show up. I inititally used a text box, which I couldn't update, before switching it to a label. Can anyone tell me why it is not appearing? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be showing up there.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')
root.title("calculator")




display ="0"
holder = "0"
operand = 0

text_box = Label(
  
    textvariable = display

)
text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0)





def adddigit(num):
    global display
    if display == "0":
        display = num
    else:
        display += num
    print(display)
        
def add():
    global display
    global holder
    global operand
    holder = display
    operand = 1
    display = "0"
    

def subtract():
    global display
    global holder
    global operand
    holder = display
    operand = 2
    display = "0"
def solve():
    global display
    global holder
    global operand
    if operand == 1:
        display = str(int(display) + int(holder))
    elif operand == 2:
        holder = str(int(holder)-int(display))
        display = holder
    
        
    print(display)
btnTest = Button(text = display)
btnTest.grid(row=0,column=1)
btn1 = Button(text = "1", command = lambda: adddigit("1"))
btn1.grid(row=1,column=0)
btn2 = Button(text = "2", command = lambda: adddigit("2"))
btn2.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn3 = Button(text = "3", command = lambda: adddigit("3"))
btn3.grid(row=1,column=2)
btn4 = Button(text = "4", command = lambda: adddigit("4"))
btn4.grid(row=2,column=0)
btn5 = Button(text = "5", command = lambda: adddigit("5"))
btn5.grid(row=2,column=1)
btn6 = Button(text = "6", command = lambda: adddigit("6"))
btn6.grid(row=2,column=2)
btn7 = Button(text = "7", command = lambda: adddigit("7"))
btn7.grid(row=3,column=0)
btn8 = Button(text = "8", command = lambda: adddigit("8"))
btn8.grid(row=3,column=1)
btn9 = Button(text = "9", command = lambda: adddigit("9"))
btn9.grid(row=3,column=2)
btn0 = Button(text = "0", command = lambda: adddigit("0"))
btn0.grid(row=4,column=1)
btnadd = Button(text = "+", command = add)
btnadd.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
btnsub = Button(text = "-", command = subtract)
btnsub.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
btnsolve = Button(text = "=", command = solve)
btnsolve.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable passed to the `textvariable` parameter shouldn't be a string, it should be a `tkinter.StringVar()` object.

Add the line `label_show = tkinter.StringVar()`, change the label line to `text_box = Label(textvariable=label_show)`, then at the end of each function, add `label_show.set(display)`

Comment: Running this tells me that "name 'tkinter' is not defined." I've tried replacing tkinter with some other words, but none of them seem to work. Do you know what to do? By the way, thank you for telling me about stringvar, it was very helpful

Comment: This is cause by your import statement `from tkinter import*` which  should be discouraged.  It imports the entire module. For your import you would only call `StringVar()` and omit the `tkinter.` before it.  You should import with its own namespace like `import tkinter as tk` and then you call tk before your module calls like `tk.StringVar()`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you used `from tkinter import *`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
text_box=Label(root, textvariable=display)
text_box.grid(column=0, row=0)
```